# How to check if the string is equal to or greater than something?

Tags: java, android

I want to check if `strCurrentSpeed` is greater than or equal to "10".
how do i do that? i am getting error- "The operator >= is undefined for the argument type(s) String, int" i know this is pretty basic but i couldn't find a workaround

```
public void updateSpeed(CLocation location)
{
float nCurrentSpeed = 0;

if( location!=null )
{
  location.setUseMetricUnits(this.useMetricUnits());
  nCurrentSpeed = location.getSpeed();
}

Formatter fmt = new Formatter(new StringBuilder());
fmt.format(Locale.US, "%5.1f", nCurrentSpeed);
String strCurrentSpeed = fmt.toString();
strCurrentSpeed = strCurrentSpeed.replace(' ', '0');

String strUnits = "miles/hour";
if (this.useMetricUnits())
{
  strUnits = "meters/second";
}

TextView txtCurrentSpeed = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.txtCurrentSpeed);
txtCurrentSpeed.setText(strCurrentSpeed + " " + strUnits);

  if (strCurrentSpeed >= 10){
  //do action
  }}
```

Comment: Instead of checking `if (strCurrentSpeed >= 10)` why don't you just check `if (nCurrentSpeed >= 10)`? You are getting your string out of float right?

Comment: aah man, good one. what is ncurrentspeed btw? i just downloaded this project

Comment: `nCurrentSpeed` is the float variable which you declare in the first line of your function. It holds the actual value that you are getting in the string by doing `fmt.format(Locale.US, "%5.1f", nCurrentSpeed);`.

Comment: i thought the actual value is being set on the text field

Comment: Yeah but you are getting that value from somewhere right? It is not magically popping up on the `TextView` on it's own. You are filling the value of `nCurrentSpeed` by doing `nCurrentSpeed = location.getSpeed();`.

Answer (score -2):

Use Explicit Conversion :

```
if(Integer.parseInt(strCurrentSpeed) >=10)
{
  // Do you stuff
}
```

Comment: This is not a cast.  It is an explicit conversion.

Comment: tell me how to check if strCurrentSpeed is equal to or 5+ more than "10", and you win an upvote!

Comment: btw, i will have to wait another 8 minutes to accept this answer

Comment: if(Integer.parseInt(strCurrentSpeed) ==5 || Integer.parseInt(strCurrentSpeed) >=10 ){    // do you stuff here }

Comment: I want to detect if my speed is 5 kmph more than the target speed, and want to show over speed alert, 5 will be the accuracy which i can change from edit text later

Comment: than you should use equal or greater than operator like :  if(Integer.parseInt(strCurrentSpeed) >=5)   {  // do your stuff }

Comment: sorry, this is not what i am asking for, you don't win any upvotes :D